# Redux state wipes itself after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

To simplify, I have a form with a button.

```
showInputs = () => {
        this.setState({changeForm:!this.state.changeForm});
}

reservationHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.showInputs();
        this.props.saveFormPart(this.state.reservationForm);
}

<form className="form" onSubmit={event => this.reservationHandler(event)}>
{this.state.changeForm?<button type="submit" className="save">Save</button>:<button type="submit">Edit</button>}
</form>
```

Nothing spectacular. However, when I click button, my redux state completly wipes itself.
The page isn't realoading, and I dont want it to.

```
export const saveFormPart = (formPart) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SAVE_SOME_DATA,
        formPart: formPart
    };
}
```

```
const saveFormPart = (state, action) => {
    console.log(state.formData);
    console.log(action.formPart);
};
```

I have no clue why does it occur, as its the first time that code has behaved like that. The other solutions Ive seen on stack werent sadly helpful, thats why im asking for help. Any ideas?
Edit: thats not the only function i have in my redux reducer, but thats the only one that is behaving like that. Other work perfectly well

Comment: how does your reducer file looks like?

Comment: @buzatto I dont know what exactly are you asking for, ill link u this file from my github repo. https://github.com/priusGit/solvro-task/blob/main/src/store/reducers/main.js

Comment: you return nothing from `saveFormPart`, if you add simple `return state` does your redux state still wipe out?

Comment: It is for sure what @buzatto said.  Just `return state`;  Right now you are replacing your state with a `void` return.

Comment: Damn, thank you both. I was sprinting it, nad some errors, wanted to log them and comepletly forgot about returning anything. Thats true, working fine now